# Xpath Query for <input class="radio" type="radio" name="xyz" value="0">

Tags: xpath

Could you please let me know the Xpath Query for the html tag:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="xyz" value="0">
```

I tried using the one mentioned below but in vain:

```
xpath = //input[@name='xyz']|//input[@value='0']
```

Many Thanks!

Zamir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath expression selects an `input` with `@value='0'` iff it is a descendant of an `input` with `@name='xyz'` that is anywhere in the document.

So, your expression *could* match the element you want, but only in that specific context (which I assume it isn't in, as it is not matching).

Your desired element could be matched by any of the following:

- `//input`
- `//input[@name='xyz']`
- `//input[@value='0']`
- `//input[@name='xyz' and @value='0']`
- `//input[@name='xyz'][@value='0']`
- `//*[@name='xyz'][@value='0']`

Which you choose would depend on what it is you *don't* want to match.

You might also wish to consider not starting with `//` as that searches the entire document.  If you know more about the ancestry of the element in question, you could add that information to achieve a more targeted match.